# How should I handle reviewer comments when grammar makes the meaning unclear?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, paper-submission

I have received reviewer comments on a paper that I had sent to a journal. Now although the reviews look good, there are lot of grammar mistakes in it making it difficult to understand some of them.

How do I handle these kind of reviews? Is it okay to write to the editor’s office for clarifications? I guess that way, the process would take a long time.

Comment: @thomas It doesn't get easier to understand bad grammar when your own grammar isn't that good either. In other words, a (near) native speaker can easily understand broken language, but a broken speaker will have a hard time to do so.

Comment: @Thomas another way to look at that: lack of English fluency *on either side* impedes communication in English, so if the OP isn't a native speaker that may explain why they're finding this review harder to read than some of us might.

Comment: @Mark "all perfect English is alike; every imperfect English is imperfect in its own way".

Comment: I think Dawn's suggestion of how to deal with these comments is excellent, both getting a second opinion and restating your understanding of the comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, work through the comments with someone else to parse their meaning as closely as possible. A native speaker might be able to explain what the reviewer was trying to say in his/her comments. If several people are not able to understand or do not agree, then you may contact the editor for clarification. But try not to reach this point--nothing in the snippet you have provided seems that problematic.

Next, revise and resubmit as directed by the journal editor. In your response to reviewer comments, I would create a numbered list of comments. Before stating how you addressed each comment, you should briefly restate your understanding of what the comment was conveying. If you have not adequately addressed the comment because you did not understand it, then this should at least prompt the reviewer to clarify their comment, rather than become annoyed at your response.